Angular 17.3 SSR with standalone components
I succeeded in converting my Angular 16.0 app to 17.3. Then I added Angular SSR, that also worked. Both npm run build:ssr and npm run serve:ssr succeed.
Then I used the schematic ng add @angular/ssr to migrate from ngModules to standalone components. That worked fine: ng run start succeeded. But when I ran npm run build:ssr to create a ssr app an error appeared during the browser application generation stage, saying it missed the Appmodule in ./app.module.ts. I found this link: https://dev.to/ayyash/angular-standalone-in-ssr-update-1n42. This looks rather elaborate and applies to Angular v17.0, I'm now at 17.3
Is it now or in the near future possible to create an Angular SSR app from an app with standalone components using the Angular CLI? And if not, what is the recommended way to do this?

Angular 17 standalone components currently do not have direct support for Server-Side Rendering (SSR) out of the box. While SSR is a core functionality of the Angular framework, it's primarily designed for applications built using the traditional NgModule-based approach.

well, using Angular v17.3 ng cli for generating an app with SRR, uses standalone components by default.
I would suggest to create a brand new app with ng cli just for comparing with your current app.

@Joey SS that statement is false. You can use Angular with standalone components and SSR out of the box. I am using it like that. Seems to me OP's issue is related to migrating from ngModules to standalone components. SSR can however be related to the issue. I myself found some strange behaviors when enabling SSR (ie: when using 'fileReplacements' in my 'angular.json' the build would get stuck for some reason) but without extra error details, its hard to help
